# Chapter number in exercise ref

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, exercises

I'd like exercise references to include the chapter number. Notice in the screenshot below that the reference is "figure 0.1" but only "exercise 1". I'd like the exercise ref to include the chapter number, so that I can reference exercises across chapters.

I'm working in overleaf (pdfLaTex 2022). Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{exercise}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\newcommand{\QuestionNB}{\bfseries\thechapter.\arabic{Question}.}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{}

% I thought the following line should do the trick
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\thechapter.\arabic{Exercise}}%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

see exercise \ref{thisref} and figure \ref{fig}

\section{Exercises}
\begin{Exercise}
  \Question \label{thisref} \lipsum[1]
\end{Exercise}
 
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{figure.png}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I was close, but the correct command to renew seems to be theQuestion and not theExercise. So:

```
% this seems to do nothing:
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\thechapter.\arabic{Exercise}}

% this one is correct:
\renewcommand{\theQuestion}{\thechapter.\arabic{Question}}
```

Comment: Hi Steven. Please accept your own answer in order to not let the question marked as opened. Thanks.